# Склонение имени и фамилии

Tags: стилистика, склонение-фамилий

Почему, склоняя по падежам имя-фамилию Робин Гуд, мы говорим "Робин Гуда" и т.д., а не "Робина Гуда"? Я могу допустить, что это уже устоявшаяся конструкция (особенно, когда мы говорим в переносном значении о бескорыстном человеке), но почему тогда имя и фамилия не слились в одно слово, как произошло, например, с донжуаном? Та же ситуация с Дон Кихотом.

Answer (score 2):

1. В русском языке сложилась традиция употреблять фамилии ряда иностранных деятелей (преимущественно писателей) в сочетании с именами: *Вальтер Скотт, Жюль Верн, Майн Рид, Конан Дойль, Брет Гарт, Оскар Уальд, Ромен Роллан;* ср. также литературные персонажи: *Робин Гуд, Шерлок Холмс, Нат Пинкертон*. Употребление этих фамилий отдельно, без имен, мало распространено (в особенности это касается односложных фамилий; вряд ли кто-нибудь читал в детстве Верна, Рида, Дойля и Скотта!).

   Следствием такого тесного единства имени и фамилии оказывается склонение в косвенных падежах только фамилии: *Вальтер Скотта*, *Жюль Верну, с Майн Ридом, о Робин Гуде* и т. п. Это явление, характерное для непринужденной устной речи, находит отражение и на письме. (По [материалам «Грамоты»](http://www.gramota.ru/biblio/magazines/gramota/kultura/28_616)).

   Т.е. в устной речи и в письменной, передающей устную, вполне допустимо употребление типа «прочитал о Робин Гуде». Строгая же литературная норма требует изменения: «В легендах о Робине Гуде».
2. Говоря о Дон Жуане как литературном герое или исторической личности, мы все-таки имя и фамилию его пишем раздельно и с большой буквы, так как это имя собственное. От него образовалось слово *донжуан* — волокита, человек, проводящий жизнь в любовных приключениях. Это уже другое слово. Нарицательное существительное со своим значением. И его могут знать те. кто и понятия не имеет о Дон Жуане — литературном герое. Да, с Робин Гудом такого не произошло. Может. потому, что образ не такой однозначный. И не просто Робин Гуд символ бескорыстия, а, может, символ благородства, символ борьбы за свободу,борьбы против власть имущих. И кого мы можем назвать сейчас Робин Гудом так же запросто, как ловеласа — донжуаном?

Comment: Да, Робин - образ неоднозначный. Для меня он скорее буян-гуляка не без благородства. Этакий английский Самсон, только без эффектного трагического облагораживающего конца. А вот Дон Кихот - образ довольно ясный. Как раз про него можно спросить"кого мы можем назвать сейчас ..."

Answer (score 1):

У Дон Жуана и Дон Кихота часть "дон" первоначально не являлась частью имени. Дон или Дом (исп. и итал. don, франц. и порт. dom, от лат. dominus — господин) — титул в некоторых странах Европы. В Испании этот титул, прежде принадлежавший королю и принцам, потом жаловался за заслуги, теперь просто уважительное обращение к мужчине. В Италии — почётный титул духовенства и дворян, изначально дававшийся только Папе. В Португалии титул дона носят владетельные особы и члены их фамилий. Отсюда - донья (исп. — doña) и донна (ит. donna, португ. dona) — обращения к женщине.